# How to get percentage in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, percentage

I'm having a problem in my query. I can't get the percentage, no matter how i try. Please help me. I need to get the percent create and close time of POS and NON-POS weekly in individual query. I've always get an error. Thanks!

Query:

For POS:

```
SELECT 'Data'
||','||COUNT(CASE WHEN UPPER(TICKET_CUSTOMER_USER_ID) = UPPER('POS-generic') THEN 1 ELSE     NULL END) --POS
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET
WHERE TRUNC(CREATE_TIME, 'IW') BETWEEN SYSDATE -119 AND SYSDATE -1
AND trunc(CLOSE_TIME, 'IW')  BETWEEN SYSDATE -119 AND SYSDATE -1;
```

For NON POS

```
  SELECT 'Data'
||','||COUNT(CASE WHEN UPPER(TICKET_CUSTOMER_USER_ID) = UPPER('hcphuser') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) --NON_POS
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET
WHERE TRUNC(CREATE_TIME, 'IW') BETWEEN SYSDATE -119 AND SYSDATE -1
AND trunc(CLOSE_TIME, 'IW')  BETWEEN SYSDATE -119 AND SYSDATE -1;
```

Some output of database:

```
Name                           ticket_customer_id create_time   close_time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cannot access the Zimbra Email POS-generic        10/15/2013    10/15/2013 
Slow WIFI Connection           POS-generic        10/15/2013    10/16/2013
Change phone number            hcphuser           10/17/2013    10/18/2013
```

Output sample need:

FOR POS

```
 Data, 10/10/2013, 50, 60%
 Data, 10/17/2013, 30, 40%
```

FOR NON POS

```
 Data, 10/10/2013, 70, 60%
 Data, 10/17/2013, 50, 40%
```

Comment: The fact that you've provided the desired output is great, but you forgot to provide the input - from what input you want to produce that output? Sample of source data would be useful to have, as well.

Comment: sorry. i update now the content of my question

Comment: Calculating percentages should presumably involve division of some sort, while there is no division operator in your queries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an inner select.. Try this

```
SELECT 'Data', POS, NON_POS, ROUND((POS*100 / (NON_POS + POS)),2) NON_POS_PERCENTAGE, 100 - ROUND((POS*100 / (NON_POS + POS)),2) POS_PERCENTAGE 
  FROM (
        SELECT 70 POS,
               30 NON_POS
        FROM DUAL
        )

         SELECT 'Data', POS, NON_POS, ROUND((POS*100 / (NON_POS + POS)),2) NON_POS_PERCENTAGE, 100 - ROUND((POS*100 / (NON_POS + POS)),2) POS_PERCENTAGE 
      FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN UPPER(TICKET_CUSTOMER_USER_ID) = UPPER('POS-generic') THEN 1 ELSE     NULL END) POS,
                   COUNT(CASE WHEN UPPER(TICKET_CUSTOMER_USER_ID) = UPPER('hcphuser') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) NON_POS
            FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET
            WHERE TRUNC(CREATE_TIME, 'IW') BETWEEN SYSDATE -119 AND SYSDATE -1
            AND trunc(CLOSE_TIME, 'IW')  BETWEEN SYSDATE -119 AND SYSDATE -1
            )
```

Comment: there's an error: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: a comma was missing. can you check it again

Comment: it's working but wrong output. the output i need is weekly result wiht date but the display result in your query is only the total :|

Comment: @user3172075: Are you asking *two* questions then? "How to group data weekly" and "How to get percentage of a total"? If so, please let this one be about the percentage only, please ask the one about grouping by weeks *separately*. It is really not a good idea to ask about more than one thing in the same question on this site.